# Convert code from VBA to SQL (fixing zip codes)

Tags: mysql, sql, vba

I downloaded a dataset from the internet and it was ill formatted. The zip codes are breaking my website. Some are the full 9 integer codes, others are 2 or 3 integers because the leading zeros didn't get formatted correctly, and everything in between. I need the normal 5 digit zip code for my site to work. The dataset is also over 2 million lines so it's difficult to work in Excel. I was hoping to get it working in MySQL.

I have written code in VBA and tested it on parts of the data in Excel and i get the desired results.

```vb
Function fixZips()

    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Application.Selection

        If Len(cel.Value) = 4 Then
            cel.Value = "0" & cel.Value

        ElseIf Len(cel.Value) = 3 Then
            cel.Value = "00" & cel.Value

        ElseIf Len(cel.Value) = 2 Then
            cel.Value = "000" & cel.Value

        ElseIf Len(cel.Value) = 7 Then
            cel.Value = "00" & Left(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value) - 4)

        ElseIf Len(cel.Value) = 8 Then
            cel.Value = "0" & Left(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value) - 4)

        ElseIf Len(cel.Value) = 9 Then
            cel.Value = Left(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value) - 4)

        End If

    Next cel

End Function
```

I am having the hardest time figuring out how to do this in MySQL. I am using phpMyAdmin. Can I do this all in the SQL box? Do I need to create a stored procedure? If so, how do I do that in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I recommend looking at case/when/else. It'll be big and ugly, but it'll be pretty much what you already have, just in sql :)

Comment: Did you get the data set as an Excel file, or a CSV? If it's the later, just don't open it in Excel.

Comment: In VBA too you wouldn't do it like that :) What if you were dealing with a code that is 1000 in length instead of 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use pure SQL and have the MySQL engine process the needed results and not the Excel application. Below is the long-winded version to show how your Excel VBA can translate to SQL. Additionally, using `CASE` and double pipes is the ANSI standard and should work across most SQL dialects.

**Select SQL**

```sql
SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';

SELECT bad_zip, LENGTH(bad_zip),

       CASE LENGTH(bad_zip)
            WHEN 2 THEN '000' || bad_zip
            WHEN 3 THEN '00' || bad_zip
            WHEN 4 THEN '0' || bad_zip
            WHEN 7 THEN '00' || LEFT(bad_zip, LENGTH(bad_zip) - 4)
            WHEN 8 THEN '0' || LEFT(bad_zip, LENGTH(bad_zip) - 4)
            WHEN 9 THEN LEFT(bad_zip, LENGTH(bad_zip) - 4)
            ELSE bad_zip
       END As clean_zip

FROM myTable;
```

**Update SQL**

```sql
SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';

UPDATE myTable 
SET    final_zip = CASE LENGTH(bad_zip)
                        WHEN 2 THEN '000' || bad_zip
                        WHEN 3 THEN '00' || bad_zip
                        WHEN 4 THEN '0' || bad_zip
                        WHEN 7 THEN '00' || LEFT(bad_zip, LENGTH(bad_zip) - 4)
                        WHEN 8 THEN '0' || LEFT(bad_zip, LENGTH(bad_zip) - 4)
                        WHEN 9 THEN LEFT(bad_zip, LENGTH(bad_zip) - 4)
                        ELSE bad_zip
                   END;
```

[RexTester Demo](http://rextester.com/YHNF83088)

Comment: Yep. Skip Excel *entirely*. The bit about "is also over 2 million lines" is a pretty good hint that the OP's file isn't an Excel file to begin with...

Comment: Indeed @Comintern ... data could be in multiple sheets! I have seen insane things done in Excel, forgetting it is not a database.

Comment: This code worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Been pulling my hair out for hours.

Answer (score 4):

for a sql query you could use a substr and lpad

```
 select lpad(substr(your_column, 1,5), 5, '0') 
 from your_table
```